# how to configure cygwin Local Package Directory

Tags: windows, directory, package, cygwin, config

I have to change my cygwin Local Package Directory, which happen to be earlier as `C:\Users\username\Downloads`.

Folders like `http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f` are all in place in my new directory for Local Package Directory.

How to do that? (I cannot find, where cygwin stores the config.)

Running setup from new location tries to install all over again instead from continue using earlier packages from the internet.

Answer (score 4):

The information is on `/etc/setup/setup.rc`

```
$ head setup.rc
last-cache
        e:\downloads\cygwin_cache
last-mirror
        http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/
net-method
        Direct
last-action
        Download,Install
mirrors-lst
....
```

Please note that setup just propose the settings based on last run but you can always change typing new values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Somehow 
/etc/setup/setup.rc
seems to be not accessible for setup executable, yet in place, in my 
my-some-path-to-cygwin\cygwin\etc\setup\setup.rc.

Comment: The contents of setup.log is :
2017/10/08 03:05:08 Starting cygwin install, version 2.873
2017/10/08 03:05:08 User has backup/restore rights
2017/10/08 03:05:08 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/setup.rc) failed 2 No such file or directory
2017/10/08 03:05:08 Current Directory: my-some-path-to-cygwin-logged-ok\cygwin

Comment: 2017/10/08 03:05:08 Could not open service McShield for query, start and stop. McAfee may not be installed, or we don't have access.
2017/10/08 03:05:12 source: network install
2017/10/08 03:05:31 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/setup.rc) failed 2 No such file or directory
2017/10/08 03:05:31 Ending cygwin install

What else should i do to make work OK?
bin\ folder of cygwin is in my path, git and bash works ok.

Comment: how do i change cygwin settings and configure the setup?

Comment: Oh, yes. Setup.exe isn't just gui, and can be configured from command line.
But may be some config files could be edited by hand?